# Unable to delete a row in a table without any foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete rows from a table in SQL Server 2008 that has **neither any foreign key constraints nor any triggers**. When I check the message section, it is showing the rows affected but when I check the table, rows are still present. Attached is the image for reference. I am very much sure that there no constraints to this table. What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: what constraint are you referring to.  Please identify the constraint

Comment: (i can't see the image, srry) Are you sure you deleting and selecting from the same table? (Same database/same schema)

Comment: primary/foreign keys or default constraints.

Comment: Common causes: trigger (which you've already mentioned), transactions not set to "auto commit" in SSMS (try placing a `commit` after the `delete` to see if this is the case), the wrong DBO (delete from `whywake.HrOrganization` but select from `whynot.HrOrganization`. You can rule out constraints because they'll throw an exception and SSMS will report it.

Comment: yes it is the same table from the same schema on the same database on the same server

Comment: Quite often one tests against one database and checks the result in another instance... Might be an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`...

Comment: You've executed 2 statements, but SMSS shows 3 separate counts of affected rows. Are you sure you don't have a trigger on your table?

Comment: edited the image with database and schema names and tried transaction as well, but no luck. Yes SSMS is showing 3 separate counts of affected rows which is quite weird specially when I have no triggers.

Comment: Your `HrOrganisation` doesn't have FK but some other table has FK which refer to PK of `HrOrganisation`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys tables to query constrints, keys, etc.  Based upon these results, you can delete from your table.  Please see below for a sample query which returns table constraints.

```
    SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    dc.type,
    dc.type_desc,
    dc.name,
    dc.definition
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints dc ON t.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
where t.name = 'yourtablename'
ORDER BY t.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If there truly is no trigger on the table you're deleting from, then examine all the linked tables that have FKs to the table you're deleting from (and, in turn, all FKs to those tables). The FKs would have `ON DELETE CASCADE` set so that the delete actually works (instead of throwing an error), only, a trigger in any of those FK-bearing tables could be immediately re-adding the rows.

You might not necessarily see a `rows affected` message for all of these potential trigger operations, because triggers can set `SET NOCOUNT ON` before doing any DML...